# How to make changes in the react webpage in github pages?

Tags: reactjs, git, branch

I had deployed me react webpage successfully in the `main` branch. There are my main source files, take a look [Main branch](https://github.com/shivkaansh/Amazon_clone_reactJS/tree/main). And after deployment, branch `gh-pages` has all necessary files containing like a static folder and all... take a look here [gh-pages branch](https://github.com/shivkaansh/Amazon_clone_reactJS/tree/gh-pages).

But whenever I change in the `main` branch, it does not reflect the webpage. Is there any way to push all my changes??

I am unable to push changes to the `gh-pages` branch as I am afraid because it is having totally different files.

How can I do these changes??

I had followed these git commands, but it didn't work

```
$ git add .
$ git status // to see what changes are going to be commited
$ git commit -m 'Some descriptive commit message'
$ git push origin master

$ git checkout gh-pages // go to the gh-pages branch
$ git rebase master // bring gh-pages up to date with master
$ git push origin gh-pages // commit the changes
$ git checkout master // return to the master branch
```

Referred from [here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/easily-keep-gh-pages-in-sync-with-master/)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have these scripts in your package.json file, then you can just run `npm run deploy`

```
"scripts": {
//...
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```